# how to remove the 1px under the image?

Tags: css

http://down123.xxmn.com/wemade/
there is no padding or margin under the image. but i don't know why there is  about 1px under the image.which locates at the top right of the page.
[image]

how to remove the 1px which ix under the image? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Andres' solution works, it doesn't actually deal with the issue directly, which is the vertical alignment of the image. The way to fix it is to give the image an alignment other than `baseline`, such as `top` or `bottom`.

This is what I usually use:

```
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This way you aren't 'hacking' together a solution by changing the image's natural display mode, but rather dealing with the problem directly.

Also, if you are worried about the way that the inline anchor wraps the inline image, then change the display mode on the anchor, not the image (i.e. block or inline-block).

Answer (score 1):

Just define your image as a block level element to allow your link to properly wrap around your image;

```
#top a img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: +1 I always solved this with `line-height: 0`. This is a much better fix.

Comment: @Eric was gunning for that fix as well until i noticed that the link was not wrapping itself to the image properly.

Comment: @Eric I have answered with the solution to the actual problem, rather than a workaround. This may be of interest to you both?

Comment: @joshnh while that may work it still doesn't properly wrap the link around the image, which is inline by default. `vertical-align` simply shifts the alignment of the image within an inappropriately contained element.

Comment: @AndresIlich Actually, it does. It just doesn't appear that way in Chrome's web inspector due to the inline nature of both images and anchor elements. If you need further evidence of this then simply hover over the image; no matter where you hover, the cursor is a pointer (indication of a link).

Comment: @joshnh an anchor is still an anchor, so it will still show the cursor, the problem is the way the anchor is wrapping around the image. Take for example this fiddle: [test 1](http://jsfiddle.net/sNqv3/), notice how the red background i added to the anchor remains on the baseline of the container while the image overflows outside of it. Now notice this fiddle with your fix: [test 2](http://jsfiddle.net/sNqv3/1/), notice how the image shifted but the containment of the anchor remained the same, that is the problem. With proper containment, the anchor should wrap around the image.

Comment: @AndresIlich Also, your statement about the parent element inappropriately containing the image is incorrect. Parents naturally contain their children, and this is no exception. The only issue is that when an inline element is vertically aligned to the baseline, it has to leave room for descenders. So parent containers also must account for this. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/9FRWa/

Comment: @AndresIlich Your two examples only illustrate the point I'm trying to make... The anchor element simply allows for any descenders that the inline image might have. Now obviously it doesn't have any, but that is what the default of vertical-align: baseline; causes.

Comment: @AndresIlich Upon further examination, I think I understand the point you are trying to make. But even then, the correct solution is to give the anchor a display of block or inline-block, not the image. Setting display: block; on the image because of the behavior of the anchor isn't dealing with the issue at hand, despite the fact that it might work.

Comment: @joshnh that to me does not compute, the whole point of the box model is proper containment. When an element is not properly contained then the box model failed. A container cannot just align the content within without properly wrapping it, but im digressing.

Comment: @joshnh also, took a look at your demo and noticed that you used a div instead of an anchor, divs are naturally block level elements so it is not the same. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/9FRWa/5/) is a better representation of what im trying to explain.

Comment: @AndresIlich Right, so we were clearly talking about different things, but I believe we understand each other now. In regards to that jsFiddle you updated, refer to my comment before this one (note that you changed the display on the div, not the image. That's exactly what I explain in my previous comment). Oh, and there is a lot about the box model that doesn't compute, that's why older versions of IE used a different model; one that is being reintroduced with the use of box-sizing!

Comment: @AndresIlich Also, here is a pretty straight forward example that shows that setting display: block; on the image doesn't work as desired (the anchor still doesn't containt correctly, as the display mode needs to be changed on the anchor, not the image): http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/VxA5Y/. And here is it again, but done correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/aZfra/. So hopefully you can see my point that you should always try and fix the actual problem, rather than use a workaround.

Comment: @joshnh thats confusing, in the link posted by OP that scenario is not the same as in the fiddle of yours, and even if it doesn't seem proper to me to layout a logo image along with text in such a way. We have our different ways of doing things, i guess there is really no confusion just different ways of doing things.

Comment: @AndresIlich That's what I'm talking about though. I was attempting to illustrate that by incorrectly dealing with the issue, you will encounter times where it doesn't work as expected. I'm not sure how else to explain it to you!